# Adding red dot to tip of trajectory animation under specific conditions

Tags: graphics, animation

I have the following little bit of code that models a thrust force being applied to a point-mass, and was wondering if it's possible to add a red dot to the "tip" of the animated trajectory when thrust is being applied.

```
Remove["Global`*"]
g = 9.81; (*Gravitational acceleration*)
m0 = 50000; (*Initial mass*)
T = 1200000;(*Thrust*)
Isp = 300; (*Specific impulse*)
tmax = 1000;(*Maximum value for t*)
theta = 177;(*Thrust angle*)

Solution = NDSolve[{
   x''[t] == If[t < 30, T/m[t] Cos[theta Degree], 0],
   y''[t] == If[t < 30, T/m[t] Sin[theta Degree], 0] - g, 
   m'[t] == If[t < 30, -(T/(g Isp)), 0],
   x[0] == 100000, y[0] == 100000, x'[0] == 1900 Cos[70 Degree], 
   y'[0] == 1900 Sin[70 Degree], m[0] == m0}, {x[t], y[t], x'[t], 
   y'[t], m[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}, MaxSteps -> 1000000]

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. Solution], {t, 0, tmax}, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y}, PlotRange -> {{0, 900000}, {0, 300000}}, 
 PlotStyle -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large]
Animate[ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. Solution], {t, 0, a}, 
  AxesLabel -> {x, y}, PlotRange -> {{0, 900000}, {0, 300000}}, 
  PlotStyle -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large], {a, 0, tmax}, 
 AnimationRate -> 5, AnimationRepetitions -> 1]
```

Comment: I think you'd be better off solving for `{x, y, m}` instead of `{x[t], y[t] ...}`. You can access coordinates in a more natural way and still get to the derivatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add something alike as an option to the `ParametricPlot`.

```
Epilog -> If[a > 30, {},
  {PointSize[Medium], Red, Point[{x[t], y[t]} /. Solution /. t -> a]}]
```

Time 30 is the end time of thrust, right?

### Update: thrust arrow

```
Epilog -> With[{
   p = {x[t], y[t]} /. Solution[[1]] /. t -> a,
   v = {x'[t], y'[t]} /. Solution[[1]] /. t -> a},
  If[a > 30, {}, {
    Red, Thick, Arrowheads[Small], Arrow[{p, p + 30000 Normalize[v]}],
    Darker[Red], PointSize[Medium], Point[p]}]]
```

### Update: slight makeover

You don't have to pollute `Global` space. Instead store the problem constants under one variable as a list of rules. You could also introduce units if inputting something like "50 ton" instead of "50000" seems more natural or if you're uncomfortable with quantities without units. Let's leave that as it is for now.

```
data = {g -> 9.81, m0 -> 50000, T -> 1200000, Isp -> 300, 
   tmax -> 1000, theta -> 177 Degree};
```

Solve for `{x, y, m}` instead of `{x[t], y[t], x'[t], y'[t], m[t]}`. You can access coordinates more conveniently that way and you can still get to the derivatives. Note the application of the `data` rules at the outside of the system. Let me also introduce you to `WhenEvent`. Note the additional "equation" which stops integration when `y` gets subzero. If you're sure that will happen you can set solving time to `Infinity`.

```
sol = NDSolve[{
     x''[t] == If[t < 30, T/m[t] Cos[theta], 0], 
     y''[t] == If[t < 30, T/m[t] Sin[theta], 0] - g, 
     m'[t] == If[t < 30, -(T/(g Isp)), 0],
     x[0] == 100000, y[0] == 100000,
     x'[0] == 1900 Cos[70 Degree],
     y'[0] == 1900 Sin[70 Degree], m[0] == m0,
     WhenEvent[y[t] < 0, "StopIntegration"]} /. data,
   {x, y, m}, {t, 0, Infinity},
   MaxSteps -> 1000000][[1]]
```

Extract solving time, from any solution.

```
time = (x /. sol)[[1, 1, 2]]
```

Plotting derivatives also.

```
GraphicsRow[{
  Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], m[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, time}],
  Plot[Evaluate[{x'[t], y'[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, time}]},
 ImageSize -> Medium]
```

For the sake of plotting, endtime `a` shouldn't be zero, so I started with the smallest thing bigger. What's different here? Most noticeably the `x[a] /. sol` replacements in the `Epilog`: `x` is replaced with the solving `InterpolatingFunction` which is evaluated at `a`. No need to introduce `t` where it's not needed.

```
Animate[
 ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, a},
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 500000}, {0, 300000}},
  ImageSize -> Medium,
  Epilog -> With[{
     p = {x[a], y[a]} /. sol,
     v = {x'[a], y'[a]} /. sol}, 
    If[a > 30, {}, {Red, Thick, Arrowheads[Small], 
      Arrow[{p, p + 30000 Normalize[v]}], Darker[Red], 
      PointSize[Medium], Point[p]}]]],
 {a, $MachineEpsilon, time},
 AnimationRate -> 5,
 AnimationRepetitions -> 1]
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks very much BoLe! Do you know if there's a way to add an arrow showing the thrust direction as well?

Comment: @AlexR See update. Position and velocity (direction) are stored locally at each animation time with `With`, and then used in the similar expression below.

Comment: @AlexR Did I get it wrong, is the thrust in constant direction at `177°` to horizontal? Just replace `v` with constant vector than.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems to give a circle still, but the animation now gives "red errors" while it plays.

Comment: @AlexR Your code is a bit ... crude which is perfectly okay if you're a beginner with the system. Then I made a mistake. Anyway, my code in "Update" was updated with `Solution[[1]]` for `p` and `v`. There was an excessive pair of braces.

Comment: @AlexR Would you like me to post a slight makeover of your code to compare?

Comment: That would be great thanks! It's funny you mentioned that my code was crude, all this time I thought it was passable, but I'd really love to improve it if that's possible :)

Comment: @AlexR There's always room for improvement, for anybody. Check, compare and take what you think will improve you.

Comment: Thanks for the updated code BoLe, works very well.

Comment: @BoLe Great answer, very thorough. You get my vote:)